# how to change src of img tag using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

This might be straightforward, but i want to change the src of the img tag which is inside an li tag. There are 4 li tags and only the li tag which has class active should change it's img tag's src.

```
<ul>
   <li><img src="example.jpeg" /></li>
   <li class="active"><img src="Notexample.jpeg" /></li>
   <li><img src="example.jpeg" /></li>
   <li><img src="example.jpeg" /></li>
</ul>
```

Moreover, the active class toggles between the li tags to change the source...

Comment: why are you posting question twice!!!

Comment: @Archer Auto generated comment. There's no way to specify that it's an exact repost, rather than a vaguely similar question, though.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I know mate - it just made me lol :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
...
//code where you are changing the class
...
...

$('li').each(function() {
    if($(this).attr('class').indexOf("active") !== -1)
    {
        //Active class is applied
        $(this).children().children().attr("src", "assets/img/button_home_selected3.png");
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).children().children().attr("src", "assets/img/button_home_plain.png");
    }
});

...
...
```

Comment: What happens if there's an `li` with the class of `inactive`?

Comment: Did he specify he has `inactive` class as well??

Comment: There's no `.class()` function in jQuery. You're looking for `this.className` or `$(this).attr('class')`.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Thanks! That skipped from my mind :)

Comment: No, he didn't specify he uses that class.  Did he specify he doesn't?

Comment: can anyone solve this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907997/show-dynamically-added-navlinks-when-added-in-bootstrap-navbar

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
$("li.active img").attr("src", "notexample.jpg");
```

If you change which li has the active class then you'll need to run that code again.

If you want to change the src back when it loses the active class, do this...

```
$("li:not(:has(.active))".attr("src", "example.jpg");
```

Comment: This might sound a little late, but i forgot to tell you guys that the li tags are dynamically added only the first li is available and active and the rest of the three are added later, so you see this only performs operation once but not for all the tags....

Comment: You have to do the above *when* you add the elements dynamically, not just once.

Comment: They are changing but upon click, the src should change with the change in active class, as it toggles between the li tags

Comment: There is no event handler for detecting class changes on elements.  You would need to trigger the above code in the same code that updates the classes.

Answer (score 1):

You do it with [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) using the [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) of jquery.

```
$('li.active img').attr('src', 'newval')
```

Comment: This might sound a little late, but i forgot to tell you guys that the li tags are dynamically added only the first li is available and active and the rest of the three are added later, so you see this only performs operation once but not for all the tags...

Comment: Can you tell where you want to change the src of img?